# Returning or awaiting Task<T> in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have a WCF Websocket service:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract =typeof(ICallback))]
public interface ISomeInterface
{       
    [OperationContract]
    string GiveMeString();
}
```

Now, on the client side, thanks to the WCF I hava also GiveMeStrignAsync method at my disposal. Now, I want to create client API that uses such WCF generated async methods.
There are two  ways to do this:

```
public  Task<string> GiveMeStringAsync()   //method on client side
{
   Task<string> task = null;
   try
   {
      task = ServiceReference.GiveMeStringAsync();
   }
    catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   return task;       
}
```

Then I will await this method.

Or maybe use await inside this method:

```
public async Task<string> GiveMeStringAsync()   //method on client side
{
   string s = String.Empty;
   try
   {
      s = await ServiceReference.GiveMeStringAsync();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   return s;       
}
```

My questions:

1. As I understand async/await correctly, in the second example I will still need to await this method somewhere, so there will be more awaits. More awaits results in a decrease in performance?
2. Let's say that I am right and option no 1 is a way to go. What if, on my clients side I have some wrapper for that API (doesn't matter why). In this wrapper class I should still return(not await) Task and use await only once, when invoking wrapper class's method(which invokes API's method)?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you need is the [microsoft post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) about this, but I'll try to summarize based on what you asked:

Do more awaits decrease performance?

If you're only measuring a single thread- sure. The whole reason you're awaiting a task is so that the long-waiting task doesn't block other work you could be doing concurrently.

How are you going to `await` the Task method that is not marked `async`? There are other considerations you should have too, such as: do you really expect that try/catch to work without that `await`? It probably won't.

The simple answer is to just await/async all the way up, and don't forget about using `CancellationToken`s and perhaps `.ConfigureAwait(false);` where appropriate.